# How to publish blogs posts in local languages ( manually translated ) with language selector

Tags: wordpress, translation

I've blog posts published in English. Later I've translated them to major EU languages.

Now I would like to post them under respective language selector from home screen.

Please help how to achieve this ?

I have googled but all the solutions ask to use some plugin which does translation but I don't want this solution as blog posts are already translated manually for better quality